# How to make a trasanction cover several stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, transactions

I need to include several stored procedure in a single transaction in a single database, 
if any of stored procedure fail then roll back transaction of all stored procedure procesed in the scope.

I work with SQL-SERVER 2008

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
begin transaction
begin try
  exec proc_1
  exec proc_2
  exec proc_3
  commit transaction
end try
begin catch
  rollback transaction
end catch
```

Comment: You'll want to expand on the error handling shown here, and then test it until you're sick of it. Messed up "transaction control" can produce truly hideous results.

Comment: indeed - my simple example will not report errors back to the calling application

Answer (score 2):

You can create a single stored procedure that starts a transaction and then calls the other stored procedures.  If any of the inner stored procedures fail you can rollback the transaction.  If you tell us what database platform you're using (MS SQL Server, MySQL, etc.) people may be able to provide more specific solutions.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/080305-1.shtml.  There sample calls several SQL statements but you could just as easily call other stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

Transactions are usually at the connection level, so if you want to control the transaction through a code api you should be able to use the same "transaction object".

.Net example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k2hy99x.aspx using ado.net

Comment: If the transaction can be "contained" entirely in one database server instance, for simplicity's sake I'd implement it *within* that database call. I'd only implement it outside the database if it absolutely had to cover work done outside the database.

Comment: I don't disagree with you some people however prefer to use an ORM framework or some similar and prefer to have as little database objects as possible

Answer (score 1):

Cant describe the solution any better than this.

[Handling SQL Server Errors in Nested Procedures](http://www.code-magazine.com/articleprint.aspx?quickid=0305111&page=4&printmode=true)